# What is it that makes some cycles materials not display in the "Textured" view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view

What is it that makes some cycles materials not display in the *Textured* view? By displaying, I mean showing with the textures, not like in the *solid* view.
I have tried un-connecting the *glossy* nodes, but that makes no difference. I have checked that the *Maximum draw type* is set to *Textured*.
The bottom image is one of my problem materials, that is not displaying in the textured view. The top image is just to show that some of the materials in the same scene are displaying in textured view.

nodes that are displaying in textured view
[image: displaying]
nodes that are not displaying in textured view
[image: not displaying]

Comment: Textured view displays the active texture node. Are you sure you don't mean *material* view?

Answer (score 3):

Textured view will only display the texture if the texture is an image node.

Noise is a procedural texture and will not be displayed. You need to change to 'Rendered' view to see procedural textures in the viewport.

Comment: that is kind of what I was thinking, but then having the *gradient texture* work is what through me off. So there are some procedural textures that do work, and some that do not. How can I know which display and which do not, aside from trying them all?

Comment: @David AFAIK none of the procedural textures work in textured or material view, and they still don't even after a quick test.. Could you upload a .blend with the setup in question?